# Cannot resolve items passed from parent directive to child directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my parent directive:

```
angular.module('core')
.directive 'navBar', ->
  templateUrl: 'core/templates/navbar.tpl.html'
  bindToController: true
  controllerAs: 'navbar'
  controller: () ->
    @items = [
      {name: 'hello', state: 'home'}
      {name: 'foo', state: 'bar'}
    ]
```

This is the child:

```
angular.module('components', ['core'])
.directive 'menuDropdown', ->
  templateUrl: 'components/templates/menudropdown.tpl.html'
  scope:
    items: '=items'
  bindToController: true
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  controller: ->
    console.log @items # undefined
```

Markup:

```
# navBar template
<menu-dropdown
    items="navbar.items">
  </menu-dropdown>
```

I'm trying to pass a list of object from the parent `navBar` to the child `menuDropdown`. The `items` are defined in the nav bar directive controller, but for some reason when they are passed to the menu dropdown they are getting lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to add `ngIf` to your directive in the view, so the directive won't be initialized until you actually got the data

Comment: which directive should i ad `ngIf` to?

Comment: @Alon after adding `ngif`, the directive does not render at all, even after the items are ready.